# Creating a zip file using XZip library for Win32 API

Tags: winapi, directory, zip

I am trying to zip up a folder using the XZip library. I have a `TCHAR` variable array, `filename`, that holds the directory of the folder I want to zip, where `filename` is set to `L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\NewFolder\\"`.

The XZip library says to add the `XZip.h` file and `XZip.cpp` file to the project, so I did. And I added `#include "XZip.h"` to my project file, and then used the `CreateZipZ()` function from the XZip library which is used to create a zip archive file (by name): Ex:

```
CreateZipZ("c:\\test.zip", 0, ZIP_FILENAME)
```

But I am getting these errors:

> 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'HZIP'

> argument of type "TCHAR*" is incompatible with parameter of type "DWORD"

My code is shown below:

```cpp
#include "XZip.h"

HZIP CreateZipZ(void* z, unsigned int len, DWORD flags);
TCHAR filename[200];       // The directory is saved in this array: "C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\NewFolder\\"

CreateZipZ(L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Folder2", 0, filename_buff5);
```

Example from XZip library:

```cpp
CreateZipZ("c:\\test.zip", 0, ZIP_FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you re-declaring `CreateZipZ()` in your code? It is already declared in `XZip.h` for you.

Regarding the 1st error - there is no "initializer list" in the code shown. Is the code shown being executed inside of a function, or in global scope? I suspect the latter, which will not work.

Regarding the 2nd error - the 3rd parameter of `CreateZipZ()` is `DWORD flags`, which describes how the 1st parameter `void *z` is interpreted (where `ZIP_FILENAME` is declared in `XZip.h` as `2`).  So why are you trying to pass a filename buffer where a number is expected?

I don't think you have read the documentation in `XZip.h`.  If you had, you would see that the correct way to use this library for your task is to call `CreateZip()` (no trailing `Z`) with a *destination* zip filename in the 1st parameter, and then call `ZipAdd()` for the files/folders you want to add to the zip. There is documentation and examples for `CreateZip()` and `ZipAdd()` provided in `XZip.h`, eg:

```cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// CreateZip()
//
// Purpose:     Create a zip archive file
//
// Parameters:  z      - archive file name if flags is ZIP_FILENAME;  for other
//                       uses see below
//              len    - for memory (ZIP_MEMORY) should be the buffer size;
//                       for other uses, should be 0
//              flags  - indicates usage, see below;  for files, this will be
//                       ZIP_FILENAME
//
// Returns:     HZIP   - non-zero if zip archive created ok, otherwise 0
//
HZIP CreateZip(void *z, unsigned int len, DWORD flags);
// CreateZip - call this to start the creation of a zip file.
// As the zip is being created, it will be stored somewhere:
// to a pipe:              CreateZip(hpipe_write, 0,ZIP_HANDLE);
// in a file (by handle):  CreateZip(hfile, 0,ZIP_HANDLE);
// in a file (by name):    CreateZip("c:\\test.zip", 0,ZIP_FILENAME);
// in memory:              CreateZip(buf, len,ZIP_MEMORY);
// or in pagefile memory:  CreateZip(0, len,ZIP_MEMORY);
// The final case stores it in memory backed by the system paging file,
// where the zip may not exceed len bytes. This is a bit friendlier than
// allocating memory with new[]: it won't lead to fragmentation, and the
// memory won't be touched unless needed.
// Note: because pipes don't allow random access, the structure of a zipfile
// created into a pipe is slightly different from that created into a file
// or memory. In particular, the compressed-size of the item cannot be
// stored in the zipfile until after the item itself. (Also, for an item added
// itself via a pipe, the uncompressed-size might not either be known until
// after.) This is not normally a problem. But if you try to unzip via a pipe
// as well, then the unzipper will not know these things about the item until
// after it has been unzipped. Therefore: for unzippers which don't just write
// each item to disk or to a pipe, but instead pre-allocate memory space into
// which to unzip them, then either you have to create the zip not to a pipe,
// or you have to add items not from a pipe, or at least when adding items
// from a pipe you have to specify the length.
```

```cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// ZipAdd()
//
// Purpose:     Add a file to a zip archive
//
// Parameters:  hz      - handle to an open zip archive
//              dstzn   - name used inside the zip archive to identify the file
//              src     - for a file (ZIP_FILENAME) this specifies the filename
//                        to be added to the archive;  for other uses, see below
//              len     - for memory (ZIP_MEMORY) this specifies the buffer 
//                        length;  for other uses, this should be 0
//              flags   - indicates usage, see below;  for files, this will be
//                        ZIP_FILENAME
//
// Returns:     ZRESULT - ZR_OK if success, otherwise some other value
//
ZRESULT ZipAdd(HZIP hz, const TCHAR *dstzn, void *src, unsigned int len, DWORD flags);
// ZipAdd - call this for each file to be added to the zip.
// dstzn is the name that the file will be stored as in the zip file.
// The file to be added to the zip can come
// from a pipe:  ZipAdd(hz,"file.dat", hpipe_read,0,ZIP_HANDLE);
// from a file:  ZipAdd(hz,"file.dat", hfile,0,ZIP_HANDLE);
// from a fname: ZipAdd(hz,"file.dat", "c:\\docs\\origfile.dat",0,ZIP_FILENAME);
// from memory:  ZipAdd(hz,"subdir\\file.dat", buf,len,ZIP_MEMORY);
// (folder):     ZipAdd(hz,"subdir",   0,0,ZIP_FOLDER);
// Note: if adding an item from a pipe, and if also creating the zip file itself
// to a pipe, then you might wish to pass a non-zero length to the ZipAdd
// function. This will let the zipfile store the items size ahead of the
// compressed item itself, which in turn makes it easier when unzipping the
// zipfile into a pipe.
```

```cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// CloseZip()
//
// Purpose:     Close an open zip archive
//
// Parameters:  hz      - handle to an open zip archive
//
// Returns:     ZRESULT - ZR_OK if success, otherwise some other value
//
ZRESULT CloseZip(HZIP hz);
// CloseZip - the zip handle must be closed with this function.
```

```cpp
// e.g.
//
// (1) Traditional use, creating a zipfile from existing files
//     HZIP hz = CreateZip("c:\\temp.zip",0,ZIP_FILENAME);
//     ZipAdd(hz,"src1.txt",  "c:\\src1.txt",0,ZIP_FILENAME);
//     ZipAdd(hz,"src2.bmp",  "c:\\src2_origfn.bmp",0,ZIP_FILENAME);
//     CloseZip(hz);
//
// (2) Memory use, creating an auto-allocated mem-based zip file from various sources
//     HZIP hz = CreateZip(0,100000,ZIP_MEMORY);
//     // adding a conventional file...
//     ZipAdd(hz,"src1.txt",  "c:\\src1.txt",0,ZIP_FILENAME);
//     // adding something from memory...
//     char buf[1000]; for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) buf[i]=(char)(i&0x7F);
//     ZipAdd(hz,"file.dat",  buf,1000,ZIP_MEMORY);
//     // adding something from a pipe...
//     HANDLE hread,hwrite; CreatePipe(&hread,&write,NULL,0);
//     HANDLE hthread = CreateThread(ThreadFunc,(void*)hwrite);
//     ZipAdd(hz,"unz3.dat",  hread,0,ZIP_HANDLE);
//     WaitForSingleObject(hthread,INFINITE);
//     CloseHandle(hthread); CloseHandle(hread);
//     ... meanwhile DWORD CALLBACK ThreadFunc(void *dat)
//                   { HANDLE hwrite = (HANDLE)dat;
//                     char buf[1000]={17};
//                     DWORD writ; WriteFile(hwrite,buf,1000,&writ,NULL);
//                     CloseHandle(hwrite);
//                     return 0;
//                   }
//     // and now that the zip is created, let's do something with it:
//     void *zbuf; unsigned long zlen; ZipGetMemory(hz,&zbuf,&zlen);
//     HANDLE hfz = CreateFile("test2.zip",GENERIC_WRITE,CREATE_ALWAYS);
//     DWORD writ; WriteFile(hfz,zbuf,zlen,&writ,NULL);
//     CloseHandle(hfz);
//     CloseZip(hz);
//
// (3) Handle use, for file handles and pipes
//     HANDLE hzread,hzwrite; CreatePipe(&hzread,&hzwrite);
//     HANDLE hthread = CreateThread(ZipReceiverThread,(void*)hread);
//     HZIP hz = ZipCreate(hzwrite,ZIP_HANDLE);
//     // ... add to it
//     CloseZip(hz);
//     CloseHandle(hzwrite);
//     WaitForSingleObject(hthread,INFINITE);
//     CloseHandle(hthread);
//     ... meanwhile DWORD CALLBACK ThreadFunc(void *dat)
//                   { HANDLE hread = (HANDLE)dat;
//                     char buf[1000];
//                     while (true)
//                     { DWORD red; ReadFile(hread,buf,1000,&red,NULL);
//                       // ... and do something with this zip data we're receiving
//                       if (red==0) break;
//                     }
//                     CloseHandle(hread);
//                     return 0;
//                   }
//
```

So, with that said, try something more like the following:

```cpp
#include "XZip.h"

int main()
{
    TCHAR zipFilename[] = TEXT("C:\\test.zip");
    TCHAR directoryPath[] = TEXT("C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\NewFolder\\");
    TCHAR entryName[] = TEXT("NewFolder");

    HZIP hz = CreateZip(zipFilename, 0, ZIP_FILENAME);
    if (hz == 0) {
        // error...
    }

    ZRESULT res = ZipAdd(hz, entryName, directoryPath, 0, ZIP_FOLDER);
    if (res != ZR_OK) {
        // error...
    }

    CloseZip(hz);
}
```

Comment: The "entryName[]" holds the name of the folder/file I want to create within the zipped file, right? When I try your example, it creates the test.zip file, but within that file, it creates a folder with the name "N". I thought it would create a folder with the name "NewFolder", but it does not. Also, is "directoryPath[]" the path of the folder or files that you want added to the zipped file? As of now, it is creating a folder with the name "N" within the zipped folder and this folder is empty.

Comment: Looked in `XZip.cpp`, I see string input handling is very wonky. Passing in `"NewFolder"` as a `TCHAR[]` but getting only `"N"` suggests `TCHAR[]` is `wchar_t[]` but is being misinterpreted as `char[]`. So just drop the `TEXT()` for that string and use `char[]` only. And yes, `directoryPath` is the path to the folder that you want to add into the zip.  The `entryName` is how that folder will appear inside the zip.

Comment: Now, whether or not `ZipAdd()` actually recurses into the specified folder and adds the individual files, I am not sure. What `ZRESULT` value is `ZipAdd()` returning? You might need to iterate the files manually, calling `ZipAdd(..., ZIP_FILENAME)` for each file one at a time.

Comment: I tried changing "entryName[]" to char but ZipAdd() passes in the entryName as a TCHAR so I also changed that char in both the header file and in the function, but then I am having issues in other functions that are saying char is not compatible with TCHAR. I am looking at the ZipAdd() header file and it says that for a folder, it should be "ZipAdd(hz,"subdir",   0,0,ZIP_FOLDER);" where I think "subdir" is the folder directory. When I did this however, it created a folder named "C" which from the directory, is the C-drive.

Comment: I also tried setting "TCHAR directoryPath[] = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\ATD.pdf";" an actual .pdf file name and add it in that way but that didn't work either.

Comment: Do not alter `XZip.h` and `XZip.cpp` (unless you *really* know what you are doing). Restore them, and fix your code to pass in what they are actually expecting. And if you set the `directoryPath` to a specific file then you have to change `ZIP_FOLDER` to `ZIP_FILENAME` to match.  Frankly, I don't like the way this lib is designed to handle strings, I think it is quite buggy.  I would suggest using a different zip library.  There are plenty of them available for C/C++.

Comment: Okay, I'll try a different library. Thank you for your help!